# fix whitespace on bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

for a couple of days, i've been trying to make this page http://www.frogonacompass.com/el/%CE%B1%CF%81%CF%87%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AE/ give height to the div.page equal to the browser's height or viewport because when the site is viewed on a bigger screen, it has the white space on the bottom after the end of the footer.

The username and pass for the htaccess are root and yjnbgy for the pass.

Your help will be a lot appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You use authentication and post cridentials on a public site? That's strange.

Answer (score 0):

Εδω Ελλαδα! Try adding height: 100%. Try to avoid setting fixed heights for elements which have sub-elements inside them. Also, the website appears to have smaller height than the browser; height 100% may fix the problem.

Comment: Can you post your code here www.jsfiddle.ne, so I can experiment with it? That will help me out! Or maybe trying margin-top: (some pixels)px to bring it down, but won't work on all cases.

Comment: Well, it works perfectly on a smaller window that the height of the website. I think that the best solution is to set the height of the middle div a fixed height ( like 500px 600px). This way, you will get rid of the white background, below the footer.